# Usar submit para submeter um formulário, dentro de modal, usando bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, twitter-bootstrap

Estou tentando submeter um formulário dentro de um modal, só que não está submetendo o que estou enviando na tag .

Minha VIEW:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Novo</button>

    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Nova Área Responsável</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "AreaResponsavel", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "form" }))
                    {
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Descrição</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="descricao">
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                        </div>

                    }

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Meu Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var listaDeAreaResponsavel = appAreaResponsavel.ListarTodos();
        return View(listaDeAreaResponsavel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index(AreaResponsavelDominio areaResponsavel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            appAreaResponsavel.Salvar(areaResponsavel);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(areaResponsavel);
    }
```

Meu Model:

```
public class AreaResponsavelDominio
{
    [DisplayName("Código")]
    public int CodAreaResponsavel { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Descrição")]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
}
```

Debbuguei, e os valores que estão sendo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que está a acontecer? Não chega a ir ao Controller? Dê mais informações do que está a acontecer

Comment: Isso, não envia para o controller. Quando eu debbugo os campos estão nulos.

Comment: Adicionei meu Model se ajudar a entender.

Comment: Já tentou usar `<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Salvar">` (ao invés de button)?

Comment: Acho que o input funcionaria, mas dá pra usar o button mesmo. O problema, segundo esta resposta do SOen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825856/html-button-to-not-submit-form, é que que vc está colocando o `type=submit` no button, mas esse já é o padrão. Tente fazer apenas `<button type='button' class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>`.

Comment: @gustavox Tentei com o input e não resolveu o problema, tentei com o <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>, e o formulário não é submetido. Coloquei na imagem que os valores que estão sendo passados para o controller, quando debbugo.

Comment: Então, eu tive um problema parecido mas o meu era o contrário (não queria submeter o form) então achei que poderia ser algo semelhante... Mas dá uma olhada neste link: http://www.bootply.com/88094 que tem um exemplo de submeter form por um modal com bootstrap, e ele envia com `<a href="#" id="btnYes" class="btn confirm">Yes</a>` ...

Comment: Já neste outro http://www.krizna.com/jquery/jquery-ajax-form-submit-using-twitter-bootstrap-modal/ ele criou um script e colocou apenas `<button class="btn btn-success" id="submit">submit</button>` no html.  E tem tbm esta http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16154216/twitter-bootstrap-modal-form-submit pergunta do SOen com um exemplo em ajax/jquery... espero que algum lhe sirva. Abraço.

Comment: Olá conforme o @gustavox informou o que está errado é utilizar no button  o type="submit", troque para input ok.

Answer (score 2):

Precisa adicionar o name ao input

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="descricao" name="Descricao">
```

O binding é feito a partir do atributo name da tag.

Comment: Italo, e se possível tente usar os Helpers que a framework fornece. Html.TextBoxFor, Html.LabelFor.

Comment: Quando faz isso que o Gabriel falou o atributo name é adicionado automaticamente. Além de ser uma melhor abordagem.

Answer (score 0):

Segue exemplo que uso em um sistema e funciona normalmente.

```
<div id="modal-control" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form id="form" method="post" action="">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Salvar</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```